# Sequence of the ratio of two successive terms of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of real number converging to $0$ and s.t. $\forall n\in N$, $0<a_n<1$, does the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
exists?

When does the limit is strictly greater than $0$ (it can be zero if for example the sequence is defined as $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$)?

Comment: Hint:  You might try a few examples of sequences that you know that converge to zero.  You should be able to find some other limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question (existence of a limit), if you set $u_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\ln \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, what can you say about  the sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Yes, I found it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_n$ be an **arbitrary** sequence of numbers in $(0,q)$ with $q<1$, esp. it may converge to $0$, to $q$, to some value inbetween, or not converge at all.
Then $a_n:=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k$ is strictly decreasing, converging to $0$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=c_n$.

Comment: @julien: you sequence is not taking value in $(0,q)$ for some $0< q< 1$: it gets arbitrarily close to $1$, and thus $>q$ for any such $q$.

Comment: @ClementC.  I knew I missed something... Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Examine this sequence
$$1/2, 1/4, 1/16, 1/64, 1/128, 1/256, 1/1024, 1/4096,\cdots$$